# Why Eval does not display label and textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I retrieve some html codes from database and I want to  display this values in a webform.

You can see my code below. It does not display labels and textboxes. However when I View the .aspx page source in the browser I can see retrieved labels and textboxes with Eval. Why I can not see labels and textboxes in the page?

database values:

[image]

code behind:

```
using (BurganEntities burganEntities = new BurganEntities())
        {
           List<DynamicField> dynamicFields=(from dynamicField in burganEntities.DynamicField select dynamicField).ToList();
           cdcatalog.DataSource = dynamicFields;
            cdcatalog.DataBind();
        }
```

aspx:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is simply outputting the `<asp:TextBox />` to the browser; it isn't parsing it with the WebForms processor to convert it to an `<input />` element.

In your database, you should probably be storing:

```
<input id="txtsdsd" name="txtsdsd" class="textbox" onkeypress="return NumberOnly()" />
```

and then using `Request.Form()` to retrieve the value.

Comment: thank you for answer. I tried and it displays on the webform but I can not see  input id and value of input in Request.Form

Comment: Without seeing the full source of the page being output and exactly what you're expecting, it's difficult to work out what else may be needed. However, if you are expecting it to be filled in with existing data, you will need to add that as another step in your process. This indicates that you may need to rethink whether you should be outputting the `input` fields directly, or constructing them based on values from a number of database and form fields.

Comment: Actually your answer was correct fro this situation. I can see input name from Request.Form . So I can catch the datas. However it is a workaround. Because If I want to add ajaxcontroltoolkit element to database, it can not reach the  ajaxcontroltoolkit on the page. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The fast answer is because **asp,net controls are compiled server side but you using them as text** on the final render html page - so you have skip this compile, and the asp.net page did not know nothing about them.

The solution is to **avoid asp.net controls and use regular html controls**. You can still get their return on code behind, you may miss some easy to use functionality, but you can make your work with alternative way.

Other possible solution is to read the database and dynamically create the controls. For example you can add a flag on your database line that says, now create a text box, and on code behind you just create that text box dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've started to write your dynamic controls but as an addition to second reply, I would like to mention more sources about dynamic controls.

Although [there is no concept of controls in ASP.NET MVC any longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253036/asp-net-mvc-creating-controls-dynamically), you can follow [ASP.NET webform data access](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access) page.

As you want to compile your code at server side; on any postback you will loose dynamic content. So [read this](http://makhaai.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/server-side-code-code-snippet-for.html) and all done.

Or as you mentioned you didn't get values of textboxes, please see the following method,

```
var textBox = FindControl("<id_of_textbox>") as TextBox;

if(textBox != null)
{
    var textBoxValue = ((TextBox)textBox).Text;
}

</id_of_textbox>
```

see [FindControl method at this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) page